# How does this x86 addressing mode work?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, addressing-mode

Something like al will contain the address of esi + ecx + 1 ?

```
movb (%esi, %ecx, 1), %al
```

Comment: Where did you get this?  When I look at a x86 reference, I don't see any MOVB, only MOVBE and CMOVBE.  http://siyobik.info.gf/main/reference

Comment: It's GAS syntax for `mov` (on a byte argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It loads the byte at memory address `esi + ecx` into `al`.

In general, in AT&T syntax,

```
(base, offset, multiplier)
```

refers to the datum located at memory address `base + offset*multiplier`.

Comment: And if yu use it for writing code, you should know that multiplier can only be 1 (in which case it's optional), 2, 4 or 8.